# wso2 bps 3.0 cluster IllegalArgumentException: No such channel; id=74

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have wso2 BPS 3.0 cluster running (BPS master, BPS slave e G-REG).

My ode BPEL Application **use "pick" on asynchronous message callback**.

```
<bpel:pick name="receiveCommandResponse">

         <bpel:onMessage operation="commandResult" 
                                partnerLink="commandServiceCallback"portType="sl:CommandCallbackPT" variable="slResponse">
                <bpel:correlations>
                    <bpel:correlation initiate="no" set="commandRequestIdCorrelationSet"/>
                </bpel:correlations>

    ....

    <bpel:onAlarm>                   
       <bpel:for><![CDATA['PT2M']]></bpel:for>
       <bpel:sequence>

     </bpel:onAlarm>
</bpel:pick>
```

Too Often I get the following error:

TID: [] [WSO2 Business Process Server] [2012-12-13 18:40:47,131] ERROR {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl} -  Scheduled job failed; jobDetail=JobDetails( instanceId: null mexId: hqejbhcnphr7txmb25ppt7 processId: {http://wf.tigre.telecomitalia.it/WFSendCommands-BPEL/}WFSendCommands-2 type: INVOKE_INTERNAL channel: null correlatorId: null correlationKeySet: null retryCount: null inMem: false detailsExt: {enqueue=true}) {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **No such channel; id=74**
        at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.ExecutionQueueImpl.findChannelFrame(ExecutionQueueImpl.java:205)
        at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.ExecutionQueueImpl.consumeExport(ExecutionQueueImpl.java:232)
        at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.importChannel(JacobVPU.java:369)
        at org.apache.ode.jacob.JacobObject.importChannel(JacobObject.java:47)
        at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl$4.run(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:941)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:451)

Could someone please provide more information on how this could be solve?

PS: I modified my bps.xml conf with:

```
<tns:OpenJPAConfig>
        <tns:property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="true"/>
         <!-- added this line as for https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-7500  (use also Oracle 11g Driver!!) -->
         <tns:property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle(batchLimit=0)"/>
    </tns:OpenJPAConfig>
```

Thanks
Danilo

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening due to a missing instance lock in the initial instance creation. You can find the more information about the bug from following issue.

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS-218

We will have this bug fixed for next release.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)